# Is there a way inside a loop to know if you're on the final iteration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

While iterating through an array (or any other enumerable), is there any clean and simple way to know if you're on the final iteration?

For example, in a Rails view you might have a collection of things to display, and you might want to put a horizontal rule between them, but not before each one, and not after each one.  Only between them. I'm sure there are many other possible uses, but this is the one I think would be most common: displaying something *between* the data of the collection items themselves.

I'm pretty sure there's no way other than switching `each` to `each_with_index` or `each.with_index` and adding a variable outside the iteration for the total count of items, and then checking at the end of the block.

Since it seems *very* unlikely that there is a built-in method of doing this with `each`, is it possible to create a method that gives you this ability without added code outside the iteration?  The simplest form (which is not quite what I'm looking for but may be a step in the right direction) might be something like

```
people.each.with_count.with_index(1) do |person, count, index|
  # ...
  do_something_in_between if index < count
end
```

But I would actually prefer something more like

```
people.each do |person|
  # ...
end.between do
  do_something_in_between
end
```

Would it be possible to make that work?

Comment: When I've been confronted with that sort of situation, I `pop` the last element into a temporary array or variable, process the main array then handle the remaining element. We should never really care if we're on element n, we process in chunks and loop until we're done.

Comment: Putting something between data of a collection - isn't that what `join` does?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use a counter or generated offset, you could do something like the following.

```
people = %w|Lily Bob Suzie|
  #=> ["Lily", "Bob", "Suzie"]
```

```
enum = people.each.with_index(1)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: ["Lily", "Bob", "Suzie"]:
  #     each>:with_index(1)> 
loop do
  name, nbr = enum.next
  print "name=#{name}, nbr=#{nbr} is "
  puts (enum.peek rescue nil) ? "not last" : "last"
end
```

displays

```
name=Lily, nbr=1 is not last
name=Bob, nbr=2 is not last
name=Suzie, nbr=3 is last
```

See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek). `peek` returns the next element to be generated if there is one, else it raises a `StopInteration` exception (i.e., if the previous `next` generated the last element). I've used an inline `rescue` clause to return `nil` if `peek` raises an exception.

To rescue only `StopInteration` exceptions produced by `peek` (and also to permit `people` to include the objects `false` and `nil`, though that is not relevant in present context), we could use a `begin/rescue/end` construct:

```
enum = people.each.with_index(1)
loop do
  print "name=%s, nbr=%d is " % enum.next
  begin
    enum.peek
    puts "not last"
  rescue StopIteration
    puts "last"
  end
end
```

We are relying on `enum.next` to generate a `StopIteration` exception when it is executed after all elements have been generated by the enumerator. [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) responds to that exception by breaking out of the loop. For that reason `enum.next` cannot be inside the `begin/rescue/end` clause.

Comment: This is very clever and I'm glad to know about this, but the downsides outweigh the upsides, as far as readability goes.  So +1, but I don't see myself using it for the purpose of making the code more readable and having fewer details for the reader to keep track of.

Comment: I thought you were asking if it possible to determine, within a loop, if the last element of a collection is being processed without maintaining its offset in the collection. I did not advocate doing it the way I described. (I'd simply maintain an index `i` and check `i < arr.size-1` for each element passed to the block.) Your title asks if it's "possible", not "possible and advised". You are familiar with how it can be done using an index, so it seemed you were looking for a solution that did not maintain an index.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : I think that for the general case (for instance, writing a general iterator which passes to the block a bool indicating whether we are on the last iteration), your idea of using `peek` and catching `StopIteration` is better than running an index, because if the collection is not an Array, calculating the size is likely an expensive operation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: yes, I still appreciate your answer very much.

Answer (score 0):

I generally use an externally defined variable to trap whether I'm on the first iteration.  I don't worry about the last iteration, as (if it's not the first) it will need the intermediate process just as all the other iterations do.

```
first_done = false

people.each do |person|
  unless first_done
    # do stuff on all but first
  end
  first_done = true
  # do stuff for current person
end
```

Properly speaking it could be argued the `first_done = true` should be in an `else` block but I think that adds slightly more complexity to understanding for the next maintainer.

Your `between` example couldn't work as the returned value from an `each` iteration is the collection iterated... the `each` would have been completed when the `between` is evaluated.

You could possibly do it by the above technique encapuslated in a method, passing a lambda... the below example is an external method but it could be an array method that you monkey patch.

Anyway, external method...

```
inbetween_stuff = -> (person) do
  # inbetween actions, optionally reference person
end

inbetween(people, inbetween_stuff) do |person|
  # normal record processing
end

def inbetween(collection, pre_action) do
  first_time = false
    collection.each do |item|
    unless first_time
      pre_action.call(item)
    end
    first_time = true
    yield(item)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own helper class

```rb
class Iconoclast
  class Config
    attr_reader :handle_first, :handle_last, :handle_between

    def first(&block)
      @handle_first = block
    end

    def last(&block)
      @handle_last = block
    end

    def between(&block)
      @handle_between = block
    end
  end

  def self.iterate(collection)
    config = Config.new
    yield(config)
    return if collection.empty?

    config.handle_first.call(collection.first) if config.handle_first
    collection.each_with_index do |item, index|
      config.handle_between.call(item) if index > 0 && index < collection.size - 1
    end if config.handle_between
    config.handle_last.call(collection.last) if config.handle_last
  end
end


Iconoclast.iterate([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) do |config|
  config.first { |item| puts "The first Item is #{item}" }
  config.between { |item| puts "Neither first nor last #{item}"}
  config.last { |item| puts "The last Item is #{item}" }
end
```

You could also monkeypatch this method to `Enumerable`. Then you'd be able to do

```rb
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].iterate do |config|
  config.first { |item| puts "The first Item is #{item}" }
  config.between { |item| puts "Neither first nor last #{item}"}
  config.last { |item| puts "The last Item is #{item}" }
end
```

But i don't like monkeypatching so this is only mentioned for completeness :-)

Comment: I could use refinements instead of straight-up monkeypatching... this approach looks promising... thanks!

Answer (score -1):

From Sebastians answer, we know that last item is at index -1, if you want to do something on everything but the last iteration you could do:

```rb
people.each_with_index |person, index| do
  do_something unless index == -1
end
```

Comment: `index` begins at zero and increases to `people.size - 1`; it is never `-1`. Replacing `-1` with `people.size - 1` works, as noted in the question, but is not what the OP wants.